# Access Devise user from AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, devise

I have a Rails application which uses AngularJS on the front-end. I also have a route in the format "/api/:user_id/submissions/:id" to access specific submissions from a user. On the front-end I'd like to display each post from the Devise user that is currently logged in, and only their posts. I have created both an Angular factory:

```
var brainDB = angular.module('brainDB',['ngResource']).factory('userSubmission', function($resource){
var service = $resource('/api/:user_id/submissions/:id', {user_id: '@user'}, {id: '@id'} );

return service;
```

And have it scoped to my controller:

```
brainDB.controller('SubmissionsCtrl',['$scope', 'Submission', 'userSubmission',
function($scope, Submission, userSubmission){ 

$scope.submissions = Submission.query(); 
$scope.userSubmissions = userSubmission.query();



}]);
```

The only problem is that the factory at the top doesn't work. I can output every single submission in my database, but I don't know how to tell Angular what the user_id of the current_user is. I have a submissions.rb controller with an action which successfully pulls all of the posts for the specific user from my route, "/api/:user_id/submissions/" but like I said I don't know how to tell Angular what the current_user.id is because current_user can only be accessed from Rails.

I've been trying to solve this for a week now and haven't found much help through Google searches. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My own app has another server endpoint call `defaults` & angular service `Metadata` that gets initialized in an angular `.run()` block.  This block pulls a `currentUser` object back (with other metadata) to initialize `$rootScope` variables.  From there, I can call other angular services with: `userSubmission.query({user_id: $rootScope.currentUser.id});` etc. in my angular controllers.

Another option would be to generate metadata content in a javascript file with all your metadata (i.e. `metadata.js.erb` in which you let rails populate variables (using `<%= =>`) that are available to your whole angular app.

Hope that helps.